# Making a Phone Call from Within PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap-plugins

In my phonegap app, I try to use make a phone call within the app. As the phone numbr is fetched at runtime, it is stored in a JS variable.

```
<html>
<script>

function callNow()
{
  var fone=client_ph;
  document.write('<a href=tel:"' + fone + '">Call Now</a>');
}
</script>


<input type='button'  id='btncall' onclick='callNow();' value='Call'>
</html>
```

This works. But I had to click twice to do this.

First **Call** button and then **Call Now** link.

I want to achieve this in one click.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your button `Call` is creating the `Call Now` link when it is clicked.  If you want `Call Now` to be available immediately just call the function after you declare it like this

```
<script>

function callNow()
{
  var fone=client_ph;
  document.write('<a href=tel:"' + fone + '">Call Now</a>');
}

callNow();

</script>
```

In that case you can get rid of the `Call` button altogether.